# How to deal with zero inflated panel data?

Tags: regression, inference, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

For a research project, I created a panel dataset that counts violent events in subnational administrative units from 2000 to 2015, thus my unit of analysis is district-year. Out of 20.000 district-years, only 2000 record violent events. Therefore I decided to proceed with a zero inflated negative binomial regression model. I understood that this model assumes that there is a reason why the population is zero-inflated, which you try to assess with the zero-inflated component of the regression model. Did I understand this correctly?

In my specific case, however, over the period of 15 years, 47% of my units of analysis experienced conflict at least once. This made me doubt if a zero-inflated model is actually necessary. I am grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, having lots of zeroes does not necessarily mean your data is zero-inflated. For example, a Poisson with mean 0.5 has 60% zeroes, but it's not zero-inflated - it's a just a distribution that has lots of zeroes.

If there truly is excess zeroes (you can check this with R `DHARMa` simulated residual plots and compare performance with non ZI distribution (e.g. ZANB vs NB), then there are two ways to deal with it, which have different One is a Zero-Inflated model, and the other is the Zero-Altered (or "hurdle) model.

The hurdle model interpretation assumes there is a process that generates zero, and if that's non-zero, there's a second process that is always positive. For example, say we were modelling "number of items bought at the supermarket in a day". If you don't go to the supermarket, you can't buy stuff. so that's the zero-generating process. If you do go (presumably) you do buy stuff, so that's the positive component (usually modelled with something like a truncated Poisson or truncate NB).

The zero-inflation model assumes there's a process that generates zeroes, and if that's non-zero, there's a second process that could be zero or non-zero. For example, say we were modelling "number of car trips in a day". Owning a car could be the zero-generating process. However, even if you own a car, you may make 0, 1, 2, ... car trips in a day.

Whether or not you need a model to deal with excess zeroes should hopefully both be informed by your theory of the behavior, and the empirical data.